# SpringLdap - Usage of LikeFilter on operational attribute isMemberOf

Tags: ldap, spring-ldap, ldap-query

I need to filter on the "isMemberOf" attribute.

I have no problem using :EqualsFilter("isMemberOf", "cn=groupXXX,ou=groups,ou=Sandbox,dc=xxxxx,dc=yyyy,dc=local")

But when I try to use : LikeFilter("isMemberOf", "cn=group*")

I get no response.

Is this a limitation?

Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing in Spring LDAP that would prevent you from doing this. Just guessing wildly here, but the LDAP server may prevent you from doing similarity search on this attribute because it represents a DN. What if you try this instead: `LikeFilter("isMemberOf", "*,ou=groups,ou=Sandbox,dc=xxxxx,dc=yyyy,dc=local")`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Unfortunately, this does not work.
I will check with LDAP admin if there is a server-side option that could let me do this.